# SilverLight Application - Error using RadExpander inside a listbox

Tags: silverlight, telerik

I need your help since I get the following message in my Silverlight application:

```
{System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
à MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
   à MS.Internal.XcpImports.SetValue(IManagedPeerBase obj, DependencyProperty property, DependencyObject doh)
   à MS.Internal.XcpImports.SetValue(IManagedPeerBase doh, DependencyProperty property, Object obj)
   à System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetObjectValueToCore(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
   à System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetEffectiveValue(DependencyProperty property, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Object newValue)
   à System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(DependencyProperty property, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, ValueOperation operation)
   à System.Windows.DependencyObject.RefreshExpression(DependencyProperty dp)
   à System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.SendDataToTarget()
   à System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.SourceAcquired()
   à System.Windows.Data.Debugging.BindingBreakPoint.<>c__DisplayClass4.<BreakOnSharedType>b__3()
   --- Fin de la trace de la pile d'exception interne ---
   à System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   à System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
   à System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
   à System.Delegate.DynamicInvoke(Object[] args)
   à StylesBudgetxaml.BindingOperation(Object BindingState, Int32 , Action )}
```

I’m using a listbox where I’ve changed the items into Telerik RadExpanders.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding FaqItems, ElementName=Root}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource FAQListBoxItems}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource FAQListBoxItemStyle}" Width="650" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"/>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="ExpanderTemplate" TargetType="telerik:RadExpander">
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}">



[...]Animation part[...]


<Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="{StaticResource Expander_BorderRadius}">
                                               <Grid>
                                                               <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                                              <ColumnDefinition x:Name="col0" Width="Auto"/>
                                                                              <ColumnDefinition x:Name="col1" Width="Auto"/>
                                                               </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                               <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                                              <RowDefinition x:Name="row0" Height="Auto"/>
                                                                              <RowDefinition x:Name="row1" Height="Auto"/>
                                                               </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                               <telerik:RadToggleButton x:Name="HeaderButton" Background="Transparent" ClickMode="{TemplateBinding ClickMode}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" FontStyle="{TemplateBinding FontStyle}" FontStretch="{TemplateBinding FontStretch}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalHeaderAlignment}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalHeaderAlignment}" IsChecked="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" TabIndex="{TemplateBinding TabIndex}" Template="{StaticResource FAQRadToggleButtonControlTemplate}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalHeaderAlignment}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalHeaderAlignment}">
                                                                              <Grid x:Name="HeaderPanel" Background="Transparent">
                                                                                              <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                                                                              <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                                                                                              <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                                                              </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                                                              <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                                                                              <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                                                                                              <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                                                                              </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                                                              <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
                                                                                                              <Ellipse x:Name="OuterCircle" Fill="{StaticResource ControlBackground_Normal}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="20" Stroke="{StaticResource ControlOuterBorder_Normal}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="20"/>
                                                                                                              <Ellipse x:Name="InnerCircle" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="18" Stroke="{StaticResource ControlInnerBorder_Normal}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="18"/>
                                                                                                              <Grid x:Name="arrowPanel" RenderTransformOrigin=".5 .5">
                                                                                                                             <Grid.RenderTransform>
                                                                                                                                             <RotateTransform/>
                                                                                                                              </Grid.RenderTransform>
                                                                                                                             <Path x:Name="arrow" Data="M0,0 L0.67,0 4,2.67 7.25,0 8,0 8,0.67 4,4 0,0.75 z" Fill="{StaticResource ControlElement_Normal}" Height="4" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Stretch="None" Width="8">
                                                                                                                                             <Path.RenderTransform>
                                                                                                                                                             <RotateTransform Angle="0"/>
                                                                                                                                             </Path.RenderTransform>
                                                                                                                             </Path>
                                                                                                              </Grid>
                                                                                              </Grid>
                                                                                              <telerik:LayoutTransformControl x:Name="HeaderContentTransform" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" RenderTransformOrigin=".5 .5">
                                                                                                              <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContent" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5 0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                                                                                              </telerik:LayoutTransformControl>
                                                                              </Grid>
                                                               </telerik:RadToggleButton>
                                                               <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                               </Grid>
                               </Border>
                </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

Do you know where it could come from?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A few more information :

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Expander_Background" Color="#00FFFFFF"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Expander_BorderBrush" Color="#00FFFFFF"/>
    <Thickness x:Key="Expander_BorderThickness">0</Thickness>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ControlInnerBorder_Normal" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ControlElement_Normal" Color="#FF000000"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ControlOuterBorder_Focused" Color="#FFFFC92B"/>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="FAQRadToggleButtonControlTemplate" TargetType="telerik:RadToggleButton">
                <Grid>
                               <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                               <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                                               <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                                                              <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.2" To="Focused"/>
                                                                              <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.2" To="Unfocused"/>
                                                               </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                                               <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                                                               <VisualState x:Name="Focused"/>
                                               </VisualStateGroup>
                               </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                               <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ToggleTemplate" TargetType="telerik:RadToggleButton">
                <Grid>
                               <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                               <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                                               <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                                                              <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.2" To="Focused"/>
                                                                              <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.2" To="Unfocused"/>
                                                               </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                                               <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                                                               <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                                                              <Storyboard>
                                                                                              <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0:0:0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusDecorator">
                                                                                                              <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0">
                                                                                                                             <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                                                                                                             <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                                                                                             </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                                                                              </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                                                                              </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                              </Storyboard>
                                                               </VisualState>
                                               </VisualStateGroup>
                               </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                               <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                               <Rectangle x:Name="FocusDecorator" IsHitTestVisible="false" Stroke="{StaticResource ControlOuterBorder_Focused}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>


    <CornerRadius x:Key="Expander_BorderRadius">3</CornerRadius>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ControlOuterBorder_Disabled" Color="#FF989898"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ControlInnerBorder_Disabled" Color="Transparent"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ControlBackground_Disabled" Color="#FFE0E0E0"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ControlElement_Disabled" Color="#FF8D8D8D"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ControlOuterBorder_MouseOver" Color="#FFFFC92B"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ControlInnerBorder_MouseOver" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>

    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ControlBackground_MouseOver" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFBDA" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFFEEBAE" Offset="0.50"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFFFD25A" Offset="0.50"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFBA3" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ControlElement_MouseOver" Color="#FF000000"/>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ControlOuterBorder_Pressed" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FF282828"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF5F5F5F" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ControlInnerBorder_Pressed" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFB69A78"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFFFE17A" Offset="0.126"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ControlBackground_Pressed" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFFFDCAB" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFFFD18F" Offset="0.5"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFFE9227" Offset="0.5"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFFFBA74" Offset="0"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ControlElement_Pressed" Color="#FF000000"/>


    <Style x:Key="FAQRadExpanderStyle" TargetType="telerik:RadExpander">
                <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Expander_Background}"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Expander_BorderBrush}"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource Expander_BorderThickness}"/>
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ExpanderTemplate}"/>
                <Setter Property="telerik:AnimationManager.AnimationSelector">
                               <Setter.Value>
                                               <telerik:AnimationSelector>
                                                              <telerik:ExpanderExpandCollapseAnimation AnimationName="Expand" Direction="In" TargetElementName="Content"/>
                                                               <telerik:ExpanderExpandCollapseAnimation AnimationName="Collapse" Direction="Out" TargetElementName="Content"/>
                                               </telerik:AnimationSelector>
                               </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
    </Style>



      <DataTemplate x:Key="FAQListBoxItems">
        <toolkit:WrapPanel>
                                <telerik:RadExpander IsExpanded="False" VerticalContentAlignment="Top"
                                                                                                                             telerik:AnimationManager.IsAnimationEnabled="{Binding ElementName=AnimationEnableCheckBox, Path=IsChecked}" Style="{StaticResource FAQRadExpanderStyle}">
            <telerik:RadExpander.Header>
               <ContentPresenter Margin="5" Content="{Binding Title}"/>
            </telerik:RadExpander.Header>
            <telerik:RadExpander.Content>
                <ContentPresenter Margin="5" Content="{Binding Answer}"/>
            </telerik:RadExpander.Content>
        </telerik:RadExpander>
        </toolkit:WrapPanel>
    </DataTemplate>



      <Style x:Key="FAQListBoxItemStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
                <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                               <Setter.Value>
                                               <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                                               <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                                                              <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                                                              <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                                                                              <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                                                                                              <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                                                                                                             <Storyboard>
                                                                                                                                             <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To=".35" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="fillColor"/>
                                                                                                                             </Storyboard>
                                                                                                              </VisualState>
                                                                                                              <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                                                                                                             <Storyboard>
                                                                                                                                             <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To=".55" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter"/>
                                                                                                                             </Storyboard>
                                                                                                              </VisualState>
                                                                                              </VisualStateGroup>
                                                                                              <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                                                                                              <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                                                                                                              <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                                                                                                             <Storyboard>
                                                                                                                                             <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To=".75" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="fillColor2"/>
                                                                                                                                             <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="{StaticResource TransparentDarkDarkColor}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="fillColor2" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                                                                                                                             </Storyboard>
                                                                                                              </VisualState>
                                                                                                              <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused"/>
                                                                                              </VisualStateGroup>
                                                                                              <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                                                                                              <VisualState x:Name="Focused"/>
                                                                                                             <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                                                                                              </VisualStateGroup>
                                                                                              <VisualStateGroup x:Name="LayoutStates">
                                                                                                              <VisualState x:Name="AfterLoaded"/>
                                                                                                              <VisualState x:Name="BeforeLoaded"/>
                                                                                                              <VisualState x:Name="BeforeUnloaded"/>
                                                                                              </VisualStateGroup>
                                                                              </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                                              <Rectangle x:Name="fillColor" Fill="#FFBADDE9" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1"/>
                                                                              <Rectangle x:Name="fillColor2" Fill="#FFBADDE9" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1"/>
                                                                              <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                                                               </Grid>
                                               </ControlTemplate>
                               </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
      </Style>
```